# Using application role to set default schema - commands unexpectedly uses dbo

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm attempting to use an application role with a specific default schema to facilitate using SQL commands without schema designations, i.e. unqualified names. I need to create and work with 4+ complete sets of tables+views+etc. (each 50-100 objects) that all should work exclusively within their own schema.

To test it, I've created an application role with a suitable default schema. I then use 'sp_setapprole' to attach this role, and 'sp_unsetapprole' to revert to my previous role. This seems to be working, as SCHEMA_NAME() returns the expected schema name (and 'dbo' before 'set' and after 'unset').

While in my approle, I attempt to drop and create a table, and then insert a record into the created table. The drop/creation works fine, but the insert fails, as it attempts to insert the record into a table with a similar name in the 'dbo' schema (which it hasn't been given permission to do).

Why is it, that my (purposedly) unqualified table reference suddenly reverts to 'dbo' even though my approle dictated default schema is another ?

It also fails when I do a 'select', which again defaults to 'dbo'.

I have granted all possible permissions for my approle to the designated schema, and only SELECT to dbo.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Lars

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because the object resolution is based on the default schema active when the batch is parsed.  So a batch like this:

```
DECLARE @cookie varbinary(8000);
exec sp_setapprole a_role,'P@ssword',  @fCreateCookie = true, @cookie = @cookie output 
--go
select * from t
```

Will reference dbo.t, even if a_role has a different default schema.  If you break it into two batches, then t will resolve to a.t.

Either that or you're using static SQL in a stored procedure, which is resolved relative to the procedure's schema, rather than any user's default_schema.

Apart from that, I don't think Application Roles are the right approach.  You can accomplish this more simply by using impersonation than using Application Roles.  EG grant the application users the right to impersonate a user who has rights only in a specific schema.  Something like:

```
    create role app_users
    create user a_user without login with default_schema=a
    grant select, insert, update, delete, execute on schema::a to a_user
    grant impersonate on user::a_user to app_users

    go

    execute as user='a_user'
      select * from t  --resolves to a.t
      select * from dbo.t --fails
    revert
```

Comment: Hi David. 
This sounds excellent, and seems to be working nicely.
One thing still puzzles me, however. What role does the "app_user" database role play in all of this ?
Is it a role one automagically gets assigned (thus granting impersonation rights) when one runs "execute as ..."?
Is it dependent on oneself having db_owner rights?
Cheers

Comment: No magic.  The app_users role is just there so you don't have to assign permissions to the application user(s) directly, and lets you manage the permissions that are granted to a user of the app, and the identity of the app users separately.